# Why does pressing Alt + Tab cause a freeze?

Tags: application-switcher

Lately my computer is freezing a lot when I do the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> combination in order to change window focus.

I don't have Compiz or anything like that.  What could be causing the system to lock up like this?

Comment: try going to System > Preferences > Appearances > Visual Effects, and set them to None. Now see if it hangs. Also, please post your Ubuntu version, and graphics hardware.

Comment: Some apps will try to do work automatically when they lose or gain focus (e.g. auto-saving their state, or refreshing/updating based on changes in the filesystem).

Is it possible you are making some apps work extra hard? Does the problem only occur when switching to or from specific apps?

Comment: I have the same problem, have just updated to 10.10, and has happened 3 times in about as many hours. Will post more details as I get them.

Comment: You don't have Compiz or anything like that? You have to say _something_ about your system, or it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: This question was closed as off-topic because it should be a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

It is more likely to be a bug with Xorg/Xorg driver, if you can reproduce the freeze please open a bug report and if you have the skills try to debug it as described at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingXorg .